# Why won't this function update the variable?

Tags: c#

I saved my variables into a string of data, and then tried to convert those string back into the variables like the following:

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    static int pop;
    static string[] log = new string[10];
    public static void Main()
    {
       string abc = "5 6 10 345 23 45";
       log = abc.Split(' ');
       Conv(3,pop);
       Console.WriteLine(pop); // expected result: pop == 345
    }
    static void Conv(int i, int load)
    {
       if (log[i] != null){ load = int.Parse(log[i]);}
    }
}
```

Pop should be 345, but return 0 instead. There is no problem when using
`pop = int.Parse.log[i]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `load` is being passed by *value*, not *reference* (meaning it's being copied). Use the [`ref`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/ref) or [`out`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/out-parameter-modifier) keyword, or just `return`.

```
void Conv(int i, ref int load)
{...}

...

Conv(3,ref pop);
```

[Check this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/NucBjY).

Comment: this answer is correct [check this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/NucBjY)

Comment: Since nothing is done with the ref parameter beforehand, why not simply _return_ it from the function instead of passing it?

Comment: @oerkelens thanks made a note about return or out.

Answer (score 3):

Although Michael's answer is definitely correct, another way to get what you expect is to change the implementation of `Conv` to return a value instead of using pass by reference.

```cs
public static void Main()
{
    string abc = "5 6 10 345 23 45";
    log = abc.Split(' ');
    int newPop = Conv(3,pop);
    Console.WriteLine(newPop);
}

static int Conv(int i, int load)
{
    if (log[i] != null)
    {
        return int.Parse(log[i]);
    }

    return load;
}
```

Or with a slight refactor:

```cs
static int Conv(int i, int load)
{
    string entry = log[i];
    return entry == null
        ? load 
        : int.Parse(entry);
}
```